# pip: command not found in iTerm but available in terminal

Tags: macos, iterm2

pip in terminal

[image]

pip in iTerm2

[image]

I try pip in both, but cannot find pip in iTerm2, anyone could help?

Comment: check `echo $PATH` for 'terminal' and iTerm2. Pip is propably not in iTerm2 path.

Comment: What does "which pip" tell you in the terminal?

Comment: Thank you! I didin't add python bin path in iTerm $PATH